# Can jumbo Ethernet frames be VLAN-tagged?

Tags: networking, ethernet, vlan

I understand that jumbo Ethernet frames are identified by a value of 0x8870 in the length/type field. (Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType) Tagged VLAN frames are identified by a type of 0x8100.

This being the case, is it possible for a jumbo frame to be VLAN-tagged? How does that work?

Comment: FYI, this is actually a better fit on [NetworkEngineering.SE]; however, SO officially allows network protocol theory questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that jumbo Ethernet frames are identified by a value of 0x8870 in the length/type field. (Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType) Tagged VLAN frames are identified by a type of 0x8100.
>
> This being the case, is it possible for a jumbo frame to be VLAN-tagged? How does that work?

Jumbo frames don't use 0x8870; whoever edited wikipedia to say that Ethertype 0x8870 is for jumbos was over-reaching.  This ethertype was proposed by [an IETF draft](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/51/I-D/draft-ietf-isis-ext-eth-01.txt); however, that expired and was never adopted.

IEEE strongly opposes changing the original ethernet spec, which [officially limited ethernet to a 1500 byte payload](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2962/775).  IEEE Chairman [Geoff Thompson](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/geoff-thompson/0/317/5b5) wrote a [pretty thorough critique against adopting jumbo frames](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-isis-ext-eth-01#section-10).  In short, ethernet is more than just a frame format, it's also hardware spec; you should not attempt to separate the two.

All vlan-tagged Ethernet II frames use ethertype 0x8100

Answer (score 0):

0x8100 just indicates the optional 802.1Q tag consisting of four bytes total. After that the actual Ethertype value and the rest of the frame follows.